# Is it possible to take into account recurrence relations using FullSimplify?

Tags: simplifying-expressions, symbolic, special-functions

There is the identity,
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(e^{-x}x^{a}L_n^{\lambda}(x)\right)=(n+1)e^{-x}x^{a-1}L_{n+1}^{\lambda-1}(x)$$
I would like to simplify expression
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(e^{-x/2}x^{a}L_n^{a}(x)\right)$$
in Mathematice with hope that elegant and simple (=containing only one LaguerreL function) exists. To do it, I have checked,

```
D[Exp[-x] x^a*LaguerreL[n, a, x], x]//FullSimplify
```

and it unfortunately gives
$$e^{-x}x^{a-1}\left[(a-x)L_n^a(x)-xL_{n-1}^{a+1}(x)\right].$$

Of course, I have tried to simlify this expression by hand but have stucked in vicious circle of reccurence relations. So, **is it possible to calculate mentioned derivative with taking into account recurrence relations**?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`FullSimplify` does not know all transformation functions.  To employ a transformation function unknown to `FullSimplify`, use the `TransformationFunctions` option.  In this case,

```
tfLb[e_] := e /. E^-x x^(-1 + a) (-x LaguerreL[-1 + n, 1 + b_, x] + (a - x) 
    LaguerreL[n, b_, x]) :> (n + 1) Exp[-x] x^(a - 1) LaguerreL[n + 1, b - 1, x]

FullSimplify[D[Exp[-x] x^a*LaguerreL[n, a, x], x], 
    TransformationFunctions -> {Automatic, tfLb}]
(* E^-x (1 + n) x^(-1 + a) LaguerreL[1 + n, -1 + a, x] *)
```

as desired.

Comment: Your answer is comprehensive but my question is not about it. I expected that Mathematica knows about transformation functions, for instance, about recurrence relations for LagurreL functions. It seems not.

Comment: @ArtemAlexandrov  In my experience, it knows many but not all recurrence relations.  I have encountered this issue with simplifying Hypergeometric functions, for instance.  Mathematica is a good program but by no means is it perfect.